# "Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account." error on Play Store

Tags: google-play-store

How can I fix the following error when purchasing from Play Store?

> Couldn't complete your purchase. Check that you have the correct country selected in your Play account.

It keeps saying that even though the country is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Detecting a country is done by various means, for different purposes

- Your ISP's country
- Your internet country (ie VPN)
- Country in your current account.
- Country of your phone manufacture

I have not tried purchasing anything outside my country, but I have installed and activated apps from other countries.

- Use a VPN to switch to the country required
- Ensure the country is correct on your currently selected account  (this can be changed once a year only) and is found

  1. Log into Google account on browser
  2. Click on settings (gear wheel)
  3. Click on See All Settings
  4. Click on Accounts and Import tab
  5. Click on Other Google Account settings
  6. Click on Payments and Subscriptions
  7. Click on Manage Payment Methods
  8. Edit the Payment Method (if one exists, or add a new one, if none are visible)
  9. The address shown here is your account's country

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it’s because of the Cloudflare DNS 1.1.1.1 that you have set up on your WiFi router, which makes it unusable in relation to the country you are using it in. Because when I tried to turn off WiFi and use the internet via Cellular 5G, I was able to buy things on Play Store immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the DNS setting on my Android device, not the router. I recommend checking that too:

Settings -> Connections -> More Connection settings -> Private DNS
Mine was set to "Automatic (recommended)"
I changed it to "Off" and was able to make payments in Google again...